# A1342 MacBook stuck on boot after upgrade

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, upgrade

I've got an old MacBook A1342 (white polycarbonate, Intel Core 2 Duo 2.4 GHz, 4GB 1067 MHz DDR3) which came with OS X 10.6.8.
I've downloaded and installed Yosemite 10.10.5 which worked fine and I also rebooted the device afterwards 2-3 times. Then I opened the AppStore and installed updates. It had like 4 Updates... 2 RemoteDesktop, Safari and a Security Update. After the security update it requested a reboot which I accepted.

Now it's stuck on the reboot. It shows the Apple logo with the progress bar. It takes like 15min or more for the bar to reach about 50% and then it stops. I waited for over 4h but there was no progress anymore. I powered off and rebooted, but it stays the same. Sometimes the mouse cursor appears, sometimes not. Also sometimes it stops at like 45%, sometimes 50%.

I have no clue how to continue. I've read that holding down CMD+R when powering up would open a recovery menu, but that doesn't work. What else can I do?

I do NOT have an additional Mac - only Windows. I can create DVDs or USB sticks.

Comment: I noticed that I can hold down ALT during power-up and then I get the option to select "Macintosh HD" or "Recovery 10.10.5". But regardless what option I double click, the result is the same. Apple logo with progress bar slowly getting to 50% and then getting stuck... Maybe that's why I thought CMD+R didn't work? It looks exactly the same.

Comment: That's a 2010 MacBook, for the record. Is it the original hard drive? I'd expect that to have failed by now.

Comment: @benwiggy that's a bold assumption and not really helpful.

I tried downloading the InstallOS.dmg for Sierra, converting it to img using dmg2img (Linux) and writing it to a USB Stick using AnyBurn. But the Mac didn't show the USB stick when booting with ALT pressed. It actually shows another bootable USB Stick I created with Ventoy though, but even though the Ventoy menu can be booted into, I just get a white "_" on a black screen wehn I boot the InstallOS.img

Comment: even if the drive failed and I replace it - how would I proceed? I failed to create a USB stick that it would boot from and I can't write the IMG I created from the DMG to a DVD because it's to big (5.3GB). Also - isn't the Recovery part of the UEFI firmware? Shouldn't it run without HDD? https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1450

Comment: I created a bootable GParted USB Stick directly (not via Ventoy) and it booted. `smartctl` shows the drive is fine. GParted shows 3 Partitions. sda1 EFI, sda2 Macintosh HD and sda3 Recovery HD. sda2 has a Warning symbol next to it. GParted said it has an open/pending journal and it doesn't show its used/unused size. I didn't let GParted to replay the journal...

Comment: I do not think you actually made a Sierra installer. I say this because answers posted here at Ask Different seem to have more steps than you used.  I installed Yosemite early last year in a VM to run some old software. I was unable to install all available updates because I ended up having the same problems you are encoutering.

Comment: "I do not think you actually made a Sierra installer"... yeah, me neither... Can you link to a proper documentation on how to do that that won't cost me weeks to understand and is full of linux commands that won't work?

Comment: Testing the hard drive on a 13-year-old computer that just stopped working after doing lots of writing (update) is the first thing I'd try. Your Mac should have firmware Internet Recovery; but a Recovery Partition on disk came with Lion. Testing whether it will boot with *any* OS on an external drive is also a good step to ruling out the hardware (other than the internal drive). Creating bootable installers without access to another Mac is not easy, IIRC.

Comment: @benwiggy already did that. The recovery does not boot (same result as regular OS). It boots fine from a USB Stick, like GParted, and the HDD SMART says it's fine. I don't understand why Apple can' just provide an ISO.

Comment: xsrf: See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/460961#460961) for making OS X/macOS installers from Windows. A user of a 2011 iMac installed [High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467923/imac-12-mid-2011-model-os-installation-issue) yesterday. The user starting with Lion.

Comment: So, a lot happened yesterday. I created https://github.com/xsrf/macOSBoot since all the previous Instructions seemed way to complicated. I got the Sierra BaseSystem on a USB Stick and booted it - which worked. First I checked the HDD and then I started the Sierra install. However, Sierra install failed with basically "Something went wrong, try again". I then tried again but this time the BaseSystem wouldn't boot properly from USB. It said it's missing some files and just offered to reboot. I recreated the Stick, but still same. However, then holding SHIFT while powering, bootet Yosemite!

Comment: Your [github](https://github.com/xsrf/macOSBoot) `Readme.md` file seems to indicate you can create a working USB installer. However, your previous comment seems to indicate the opposite. In other words, you were not able to install Sierra. Anyway, since you have booted Yosemite, can I assume you have solved your problem?

Comment: @DavidAnderson well I can extract the `BaseSystem.img`, write it to USB and boot it. It also worked once to execute Terminal, Harddisk check utility and start the Installation. So I assume the Stick I created works. I don't know why the Stick failed to boot later. I think it still depends on the HDD but that's not an issue with my bootdisk extraction process. It's an issue of how the bootdisk works in general, I guess. I don't know, I have no experience with macOS prior this. Since Yosemeite boots (now also regular again, not only safemode ?!) I will attempt the update to Sierra via AppStore

Comment: I think booting the installer is not the same as actually installing Sierra. Anyway, I was not aware Sierra was available in the App Store. If it is, let me know. I think High Sierra should be available in the App Store, although the application may only be good for upgrading.

Comment: The BaseSystem is only ~2GB so it's obviously not the whole installation (that's ~5GB), but I find really conflicting information on how this all works. I think the installer actually tried to download the installation via Internet. When I started the installation it actually told me that it will attempt to contact Apple to verify and my Wifi was actually connected (without me stting it up). I also read a lot about "Internet recovery". But yeah - I understand basically nothing.

Comment: The missing files need to be copied to the flash drive after first adding free space to the volume on the flash drive. That is not required when making a Lion or Mountain Lion USB installer. Your Mac is on Apple's [list of Macs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/101104) which can use Internet Recovery after first installing firmware updates. Some firmware updates are standalone updates and some are automatically installed during certain operating system installs/updates.